# Mysql join results from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables. 'media_id' from category table references 'id' from media table. Each item in media table can have zero or more categories from category table.

media table

---

```
| id | options | order_id | player_id |
|-------------------------------------|
| 1  | ...     | 0        | 5         |
|-------------------------------------|
| 2  | ...     | 1        | 11        |
|-------------------------------------|
| 3  | ...     | 2        | 7         |
|_____________________________________|
```

category table

```
 __________________________
| id | category | media_id |
|--------------------------|
| 1  | fashion  | 1        |
|--------------------------|
| 2  | sport    | 2        |
|--------------------------|
| 3  | sport    | 3        | 
|--------------------------|
| 4  | cats     | 4        |
|--------------------------|
| 5  | dogs     | 4        |
|--------------------------|
| 6  | sport    | 5        | 
|__________________________|
```

Have would I select all data from both tables where player_id=5 ORDER BY order_id in single query?

Response should be array(id, options, order_id, category)

I can run one query to fetch all items from media table where player_id=5. Then I would loop all results and for each result select all categories from category table where media_id=id from media table. But this would be multiple queries.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. Incidentally, options is an unlikely name for a column in a normalised schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT *
FROM media
INNER JOIN category
ON media.id = category.media_id
WHERE media.player_id = 5
ORDER BY media.order_id
```

Not sure if that's completely what you're looking for...

Comment: Ok, I tried but  (1) it also returns columns I dont want (media_id, player_id ), (2) I need to unserialize options after I get results.

Comment: Just specify the columns you want right after SELECT. I don't know enough about the options column to help with that.

Comment: I tried this but it only returns columns from media table:  $stmt = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT id, options, order_id
   FROM $media_table as mt
   INNER JOIN (SELECT category, media_id FROM $category_table) as ct
   ON mt.id = ct.media_id
   WHERE mt.player_id = %d
   ORDER BY mt.order_id", $player_id);

Comment: That's because you're specifying only media columns in your first select statement. Try `SELECT m.id, m.options, m.order_id, c.category FROM media m INNER JOIN category c ON m.id = c.media_id WHERE m.player_id = 5 ORDER BY m.order_id`.

Comment: Now it returns all columns I need, but how can I join results with same media id, so the category with same media id are returned in array? This is what  I need: array(
                     'id' => 3,
                     'options' =>options,
                     'category' => array("fashion","sport") ,
                     'order_id' => 4
                    );

Comment: I added GROUP BY ct.media_id and now it returns correct number of items but only 1 result for category, how do I return all categories for each item in this grouped result?

Comment: I managed to get waht I need with GROUP_CONCAT(ct.category) as category